# How can I customize values for genes of chromosome?

Tags: geneticsharp

I am trying to solve one job assignment problem using GeneticSharp. It is assigning gates to the trucks, and not all gates are suitable for the trucks.
Each chromosome is required to have gene values from a certain array of double values, corresponding to gene index (each gene index is equal to truck number). So, I'm trying to get a value randomly from that array and assign to gene in FloatingPointChromosome class, but this gives me an error of 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. allowedStands was null'.
Could you, please, advise me how to solve it?

```
public FloatingPointChromosome(double[] minValue, double[] maxValue, int[] totalBits, int[] fractionDigits, double[] geneValues, double[][] allowedStands)
        : base(totalBits.Sum())
    {
        m_minValue = minValue;
        m_maxValue = maxValue;
        m_totalBits = totalBits;
        m_fractionDigits = fractionDigits;

        // If values are not supplied, create random values
        if (geneValues == null)
        {
            geneValues = new double[minValue.Length];
            //var rnd = RandomizationProvider.Current;
            var rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < geneValues.Length; i++)
            {
                int a = rnd.Next(allowedStands[i].Length);
                geneValues[i] = allowedStands[i][a];
                //I make here that it randomly selects from allowed gates array  
            }
        }

        m_originalValueStringRepresentation = String.Join(
            "",
            BinaryStringRepresentation.ToRepresentation(
            geneValues,
            totalBits,
            fractionDigits));

        CreateGenes();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the case of truck and gate assignment is better you create your own chromosome, take a look on [TspChromosome](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/blob/master/src/GeneticSharp.Extensions/Tsp/TspChromosome.cs) to get an idea.

```
public TspChromosome(int numberOfCities) : base(numberOfCities)
{
    m_numberOfCities = numberOfCities;
    var citiesIndexes = RandomizationProvider.Current.GetUniqueInts(numberOfCities, 0, numberOfCities);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCities; i++)
    {
        ReplaceGene(i, new Gene(citiesIndexes[i]));
    }
}
```

Using the same approach, you cities indexes are your gates indexes.